# Creating a Vb. Net program to validate data from excel, csv, access and map to sql database

Tags: database, vb.net

Im looking to create a program that will load excel,  csv, access etc. That can then be mapped to specific fields in an sql database. I want to validate the data check for any duplicate fields if a PK, fields that are too long for the destination field etc. Also to check if fields exist in related tables. once the issues have been resolved, Then to insert directly into the database or create insert statements. Basically looking to map data to a blank database for new customers.

Really apreciate any ideas on how to go about it and where to start or if its going to be possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible.  Think of it as three sub-projects based on the source of the data.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally load a spreadsheet into a Oracle Database table.  Here's the code I use.

```
    ' path to the source file
    Dim sourceFile As String = "C:\Users\me\Documents\company\results.xls"
    ' The connection string to open the XLS
    Dim srcConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""

    ' Open the file
    Dim srcConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(srcConnString)
    srcConn.Open()

    ' Create the Query, the column names are the header row names in row one of the sheet.
    Dim cmdExcel As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select EmployeeID, Name, Department From [DATA$] Where EmployeeID is not NULL", srcConn)

    ' Load the data into a dataset
    Try
        Dim drExcel As OleDbDataReader = cmdExcel.ExecuteReader()
        Dim MydataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim schemaTable As DataTable = drExcel.GetSchemaTable()
        Dim dataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
        dataTable.TableName = "Data"
        Dim intCounter As Integer
        For intCounter = 0 To schemaTable.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim dataRow As DataRow = schemaTable.Rows(intCounter)
            Dim columnName As String = CType(dataRow("ColumnName"), String)
            Dim column As DataColumn = New DataColumn(columnName, CType(dataRow("DataType"), Type))
            dataTable.Columns.Add(column)
        Next
        Dim MyDataRow As DataRow
        While drExcel.Read()
            MyDataRow = dataTable.NewRow()
            For intCounter = 0 To drExcel.FieldCount - 1
                MyDataRow(intCounter) = drExcel.GetValue(intCounter)
            Next
        End While
        dataTable.Rows.Add(MyDataRow)
```

You should be able to validate the data in the dataset table and then do what you want from there.  I didn't post all the code, its not relevant, so this code won't compile but should get you started.